# ulimit settings in /etc/security/limits.conf not in effect for users

Tags: ulimit, oracle-linux

Oracle Linux 6.6 
Goal:  user jboss_app should be able to run up to 16384 processes

We increased max user processes because a user was running out of processes.  Current contents of limits.conf:

```
#<domain>      <type>  <item>         <value>
#

#*               soft    core            0
#*               hard    rss             10000
#@student        hard    nproc           20
#@faculty        soft    nproc           20
#@faculty        hard    nproc           50
#ftp             hard    nproc           0
#@student        -       maxlogins       4

*   soft   memlock    8388608
*   hard   memlock    8388608
*   soft   nofile    16384
*   hard   nofile    16384 
*   soft    nproc    16384
*   hard    nproc    16384
# End of file
```

When we log in as jboss_app, and run ulimit -a, we only see 1024 processes. allowed.

```
[jboss_app@tstjboss05 ~]$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 386260
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 8388608
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 16384
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1024
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

What is limiting the jboss_app user to 1024 processes after the global configuration was raised to 16384?

Dave

EDIT: IN [this serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/356962/where-are-the-default-ulimit-values-set-linux-centos/356963#356963) I found there is another file in the RHEL family, /etc/security/limits.d/90-nproc.conf, which is read when the user is accessed vi sudo.

```
[root@tstjboss05 limits.d]# more 90-nproc.conf
# Default limit for number of user's processes to prevent
# accidental fork bombs.
# See rhbz #432903 for reasoning.

*          soft    nproc     1024
root       soft    nproc     unlimited
```

I edited nproc in this file and got my desired result.

Comment: You should remove your edit and make it an answer. It's ok to answer your own question.

Answer (score -1):

Yes I tested and it worked for me too on Oracle Linux 6.9, I updated the /etc/security/limits.d/90-nproc.conf file to get the required setting for ulimit for oracle user.

In Oracle Linux 6 it is not sufficient to update /etc/security/limits.conf.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/216858)

Comment: @StephenKitt looks like this is an answer pulled from the question.

Comment: @Jeff agreed, however it doesn’t make much sense when read on its own — you need to read the end of the question to understand this answer.